# Comparing two arrays of strings to match a word.Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

For comparison, I have an array with words for which you need to check for those in the text

```
List<String> mockList = [
      'Beer',
      'Bar',
      'Cockatils',
      'Wine',
      'Martini',
      'Whiskey',
      'Drink',
      'Margarita',
      'Cider',
      'Hangover',
      'Vermouth',
      'Rum',
      'Liquor',
      'Spirits',
      'Vodka',
      'Gin',
      'Drunk',
      'Aperol',
      'Champagne',
      'Brandy',
      'Sake',
      'Mojito',
    ];
```

Conventionally, such a line that I would like to verify, there are words that are in the array for verification

```
String mockString = 'Lorem ipsum hello world Beer Bar test and another bla bla';
```

A function that checks for the presence of such words and, if they match or not, are added to another array

```
List<TextSpan> filterWords(List<String> mockList, String mockString) {
      List<String> fromStringToList;
      fromStringToList = mockString.split(' ');
      final List<TextSpan> filteredList = [];
      
      for (int i = 0; i < fromStringToList.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mockList.length; j++) {
          if (fromStringToList[i] == mockList[j]) {
            filteredList.add(TextSpan(
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 122, 122, 1)),
                text: '${fromStringToList[i]} '));
          } else {
            filteredList.add(TextSpan(
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(83, 83, 83, 1)),
                text: '${fromStringToList[i]} '));
          }
        }
      }
    
      return filteredList;
}
```

if I use a break, then it sketches everything in one color and the comparison check does not work :(
who can helps?
I understand that I'm doing something wrong, because not long ago began to study dart

Answer (score 0):

```
List<TextSpan> filterWords(List<String> mockList, String mockString) {
  List<String> fromStringToList;
  fromStringToList = mockString.split(' ');
  final List<TextSpan> filteredList = [];

  fromStringToList.forEach((element) {
    if (mockList.contains(element)) {
      filteredList.add(TextSpan(
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 122, 122, 1)),
          text: '${element} '));
    } else {
      filteredList.add(TextSpan(
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              color: Color.fromRGBO(83, 83, 83, 1)),
          text: '${element} '));
    }
  });

  return filteredList;
}
```

Thank you all, sorry I read that you can use method `contains` and rewrote the function